# Why does this array initializer throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I am studying Java currently, and I am wondering why this code throws a NullPointerException at the line indicated below. The Question object is a user-defined class that takes two strings as parameters when initializing the object.

```
public class QuizTime
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
            Quiz qz = new Quiz();

            // Throws a NullPointerException
            qz.add (new Question ("How may US states are there?", "50"));
    }
}
```

Below is the supporting class. The NullPointerException also indicates a problem with the line "quiz[count] = q;"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Quiz
{   
    private Question[] quiz;
    private int count;
    private final int MAX_QUESTIONS = 25;

    public void Quiz ()
    {
            quiz = new Question[MAX_QUESTIONS];
            count = 0;
    }

    public void add (Question q)
    {
            if (count < MAX_QUESTIONS)
            {
                    // Throws a NullPointerException
                    quiz[count] = q;
                    count++;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void Quiz ()
```

should be

```
public Quiz()
```

in order to be considered a constructor and correctly initialize your object. Otherwise, it is a method which you haven't invoked.

Comment: Wow, that was a dumb mistake on my part. I'm really a beginner at this. Thanks, that did it!

Comment: @BML0309 In the future, for debug purposes, you should add log statements to your code to see what it actually does, what execution path it takes.